# Flutter how to remove padding from ExpancionTile

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using ExpansionTile in my application, how can I remove padding from ExpansionTile?
I try to set titlePadding and childrenPadding on zero, but it isn't work
My listView.Builder code:

```
Widget buildExpandableCatalog(List<Catalog> catalog) => ListView.builder(
      itemCount: catalog.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final catalogItem = catalog[index];
        return Column(
          children: [
            Card(
              elevation: 0,
              child: ExpansionTile(
                  onExpansionChanged: (a) {
                    if (catalogItem.hasChild != true) {},
                  leading: CircleAvatar(),
                  trailing: catalogItem.hasChild
                      ? Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down)
                      : Icon(null),
                  title: Text(
                    catalogItem.name,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13),
                  ),
                  children: catalogItem.hasChild
                      ? <Widget>[
                          Column(
                              children: getNestedTitles(
                                  index, catalogItem.id, catalogItem.name))
                        ]
                      : [Column()]),
            ),
          ],
        );
      });
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The answer was

```
Card(
              margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
```